# Is every algebraic curve the critical set of an algebraic function?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

Is every algebraic curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$($\mathbb{C}^2$), the set of critical points of a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$($\mathbb{C}[x,y]$)?

In particular what is a real (complex) polynomial whose critical set is the circle (cylinder) $x^2+y^2=1$?

**Added:** For the real case we have the perfect answer by Matt F. What about the complex case? Is there an algebraic complex function  or even a holomorphic entire function whose critical set is the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: There is no such polynomial in the real case. Any polynomial $p$ which is critical on the circle must be constant on the circle, so suppose $p=0$ there. If $p$ has positive points inside the circle, then it has a maximum inside the circle, which is a criticial point. If $p$ has negative points inside the circle, then it has a minimum inside the circle, which is a critical point. And if $p$ is constant inside the circle, then all the points inside the circle are critical points. In every case the set of critical points is more than the circle.

Comment: @MattF. Thank you for your perfect answer in real case.

Comment: Comments on the complex case: If $f$ is critical on $x^2+y^2=1$ then $f$ is constant, and we may as well assume the constant value is $0$. Then $f$ vanishes to order $2$ on the circle, so $f = (x^2+y^2-1)^2 g$. For generic $g$, the critical points of $(x^2+y^2-1)^2 g$ will be the circle and finitely many other points. I see no reason the finitely many other points can't lie on the circle

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, you can also reformulate that with a Nullstellensatz. If $h=x^2+y^2-1$, $f=h^ag$ where $h\nmid g$, then the condition is $\exists b\ h^b \in (hg_x+2agx, hg_y+2agy)$.